# Copy/Cache Azure database locally for offline use.

Tags: sql-server, vba, azure, caching, database-backups

I have a piece of software that connects to an Azure database to gather formulas for several varieties of colors to allow the user to follow a recipe to create their own product.
Basically there is just one big database pull when the application launches, that pulls down all the formulas, and from there the user can simply use, modify, or even delete the formulas as they wish.

The problem is that where this software is used, there are seldom constant internet connections, and the application so far is simply designed to shutdown if there isn't one present.

I am looking for a solution for being able to allow the application to BOTH connect to the database on application startup(If a connection is present) and save a copy locally, or if no connection is present, check for a locally saved copy to work with.

I have looked everywhere, but have been unable to find any methods to "programmatically" retrieve the pertinent(or all, if necessary) data, and either export it to a local file, or cache it somehow for offline use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what kind of technology you're using on the client side, and if you require access to a database on the client or just the data - but regardless there are several ways to do this.

Azure Mobile apps have a quickstart which will implements an Azure SQL <-> SQL Lite (mobile) database sync framework (table controllers on the server side).  This lets you use libraries on the mobile side to use the local db for getting its data, and when you know you're online you can sync to/from the server.  This is quite sophisticated and probably gives you more than just the caching that you're looking for.

I've used two other strategies for caching - one for HTML/javascript based applications (phonegap/cordova) and the other for Xamarin c# apps on iOS and Android.  I'm assuming if it's a standard windows desktop app you know how to persist data so you can use whatever kind of cache/file system/db you like.

JavaScript/html - use the html5 localStorage functions to store the JSON output of the web server calls you're making.  This is really easy then to abstract, where your app before is making an ajax call to the server to get some data, instead move that to a "liveorcache" class, which can determine whether to go to the server or just use the local storage.  Code snippet for saving/loading json in localstorage below:

```
  $scope.saveFixtures = function () {
    localStorage["fixtures"] = JSON.stringify($scope.fixtures);
  };

  $scope.loadFixtures = function () {
    if (localStorage["fixtures"] != undefined) {
      $scope.fixtures = JSON.parse(localStorage["fixtures"]);
    }
  };
```

If you're writing your app in Xamarin you can do the same kind of thing, but using a PCL library - I used "PCLStorage" which works on Android and iOS.  Same strategy though, in my code I just write the JSON data to a file with an appropriate filename, but usually wrap the object in another object that contains the cache write date/time. You then serialise the object to the file - something like below.

```
public class CacheProvider
{
public static async Task<CacheModel> ReadCache<T>(string filename)
{
  IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
  IFolder cache = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("sportenzaCache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
  try
  { 
    IFile file = await cache.GetFileAsync(filename);
    var data = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data) as CacheModel;
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}

public static async void WriteCache<T>(string filename, CacheModel data)
{
  IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
  IFolder cache = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("sportenzaCache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
  IFile file = await cache.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  if (file != null)
  {
    data.CacheCreated = DateTime.Now;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync(json);
  }
}

public static async void DeleteCache(string filename)
{
  IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
  IFolder cache = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("sportenzaCache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
  IFile file = await cache.GetFileAsync(filename);
  if (file != null)
    await file.DeleteAsync();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm using WPF with Visual Basic. 
I've seen the Azure data sync stuff around, but my concern was that it throws around the term "Mobile" a lot, and mentions platforms like iPhone, Windows Phone, and Android. 
Is that functionality capable of running with my Desktop application?

Comment: Hi William - still not sure what technology you want to use to actually store and access the data on the client side.  The "mobile apps" approach is basically a template that gives you a starting point to work from, and is aimed at people writing occasionally disconnected apps - the usual scenario for this is mobile applications, but doesn't have to be.  The client side code uses SQLLite, which can run on desktop platforms as well.  You could however choose to still just cache using JSON serialised data, or your own implementation using another DB, for example...

Comment: Thanks @Russel Young.
I was definitely looking/hoping to do the implementation with Sqlite. I think im going to go ahead and use the fully capable Azure data sync, rather than simply cache it with JSON( somewhat because i have barely any idea how this is done, can find no resources to learn, and dont know exactly what purpose it would serve as far as saving system resources)
If I discover a problem, or good reason to use another implementation, I might decide to rollback from Azure data sync and use your latter suggestion.

Comment: Good luck - definitely start with the quickstart apps in the azure portal (when you provision a mobile app), they will show you how it all works, and there's a windows client in there as well you can download I believe...

Comment: "Mobile" app is really throwing me off here... There isn't anything mobile about this application lol, and it makes me think its incompatible. This is just a basic WPF app for desktop machines only. Will all these Azure mobile functionalities work with my application?

Comment: Yes - the "mobile app" bit is just a template, because what you're trying to do is the same scenario as most common mobile apps - ie. have a client connecting to a server, and enable disconnected use of that application as well (ie. cache to a local db).  There are tonnes of ways to do this, the mobile apps gives you a boilerplate to start with.  You can search for SQL sync engine or framework and get loads of other options too...